# How to ensure proper relationship between host GIDs and docker container GIDs?

Tags: docker, permissions

I was trying to setup sound inside a Docker container, so I've created an image with alsa utils installed and a user that belongs to the `audio` group. As pointed out in docs and multiple tutorials, I ran the image with `--device /dev/snd`. The result was that I could play sounds without issues, but only when running the commands as `sudo`.

A hypothesis that came to my mind to why this might be the case was that the GIDs of the `audio` group on the host and inside the container are different. I checked that and indeed, there was a difference. When I ran the image with `--group-add <host_audio_gid>`, the sound worked fine.

My conclusion is that it's not necessarily the name of the group that matters here, but its host GID. Is that right? If so, how (if possible) can I make sure that my user is always added to the host `audio` group without explicitly specifying it when running the image? If my conclusion is wrong, where's the flaw in my thinking and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

At first, avoid using `sudo` in containers (use for example [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) instead).

I'm bringing bad news, your conclusion is correct. I'm facing same problem with `/dev/dri/card0` which belongs to `root:video`. But there is the difference in GIDs. Group `video` has GID `91` on host system (Arch Linux) but different GID `44` in container (Ubuntu:20.10).

As far as I know project [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/) can solve that by manipulating CT's `/etc/group` but if you want to solve it manually without any bloat I suggest this not-so-pretty workaround:

In your Dockerfile add another group to the user with coresponding gid:

```
ARG AGID
RUN groupadd -og $AGID hostaudio && usermod -a -G hostaudio ctuser
```

Then build it with passing the host GID:

```
docker build --build-arg AGID=$(getent group audio | cut -d: -f3) -t yourapp .
```